# Browser Based Performance Testing on AWS Device Farm

Tags: selenium, appium, performance-testing, aws-device-farm

We want to use Selenium/Appium for browser based Performance Testing on AWS Device Farm. I am looking for Opensource Framework/Library/SDK for Selenium/Appium for Performance Testing specially for adding transactions and collecting performance statistics.

I have analyzed below -

Framework   Comments
testprojects.io This is free but not open source.
WebLOAD Good if you are working on WebLOAD cloud
Taurus
(https://gettaurus.org/)
It is opensource but do not have much reach options for transactions, assertions and reporting.

Please let me know your recommendations and suggestions regarding it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're going into right direction, as far as I understand AWS Device Farm concept it allows executing [Appium tests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-appium.html) on a set of selected devices.

"adding transactions" is something you can do in your own Appium code however "collecting performance statistics" doesn't seem realistic to me as all you can have is [report](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/reports.html#reports-performance) on "per-device" basis

You won't be able to control concurrency, ramp-up, ramp-down, time to hold the load, set [rendeous vous points](http://sqa.fyicenter.com/FAQ/LoadRunner/What_is_a_rendezvous_point_.html), you won't be able to correlate increasing load with response time and throughput, etc.

Moreover from financial perspective it's something very expensive, each device costs $0.17 per minute, for 1 hour test with 1000 users you will have to pay >$10k.

A better idea would be converting your tests into a load testing tool, the absolute majority of load testing tools (and there is [quite a number of free and open source load testing tools](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use)) provides record and replay capabilities via [HTTP Proxy server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) so if you convert your tests into HTTP protocol-based ones you will need much less hardware for execution (for example you should be able to mimic these 1000 users from your developer machine) and get all these nice performance metrics out of the box.